# .load в несколько блоков

Tags: jquery

Столкнулся с такой проблемой:
Есть несколько `<div id="product"></div>`, при загрузке выполняется следующий код `$('#product').load('/product.html');`, загрузка содержимого выполняется только в первый блок, а в остальных пусто.
Как решить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

селектор `#product`, подразумевает, что элемент имеет `id=product`, и, так как `id` должны быть уникальны на странице, выбирается **только** один элемент.

Поэтому вместо `id`, стоит использовать `class`, тогда селектор сменится на `.product` и будут выбраны все элементы.

Comment: по правилам да, по факту  в jquery никакой разницы нет. Не работает тут по другой причине

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev, по этой - jquery то ли со второй, то ли в конце первых версий стал выбирать **только** один элемент по селектору `id`

Comment: не должны они быть уникальны на странице. уникальность должна быть в в ветке DOM

Comment: @teran, что имеется ввиду под _веткой `DOM`_ и в чем принципиальная разница?

Comment: @Grundy в том, что пометить допустим третью ячейку в разных строках таблицы одинаковым идентификатором это нормально, и глобальная уникальность на всей странице не требуется.

Comment: @teran, и ты сможешь с помощью jquery или просто js по селектору `#id` получить обе ячейки? :-)

Comment: @Grundy я же такого не говорил. У меня претензия к слову "уникальны **на странице**", не более. Очевидно, что по своему определению _"`getElementById(elementId)` --     Returns the first element within node's descendants whose `ID` is `elementId`"_ вернет только первый узел, и он будет один. но это же не значит, что элемент с заданным атбрибутом обязан быть единственным на странице. не обязан.

Comment: @teran, судя по спецификации [_When specified on HTML elements, the id attribute value **must be unique** amongst all the IDs **in the element’s tree** and must contain at least one character._](http://w3c.github.io/html/dom.html#element-attrdef-global-id), Но я не совсем пойму какое `tree` тут имеется ввиду. Не исключено, что это элементы внутри `document` - и тогда это почти равносильно - уникальный на странице :)

Comment: @Grundy ветка родительских элементов до `body`

Comment: @teran, скорее до документа.

Comment: @Grundy вероятно, но роли особой не играет, ибо оба они в единственном  числе все равно и всегда общие для любого нода на странице.

Comment: @teran, нет, в документ так же входят теги html, head и т.д. которые не находятся внутри body.

Comment: @teran, ну и на счет _ветка родительских элементов_ не совсем ясно. Tree - может быть **полным** деревом. То есть во всем дереве должен быть уникален. Так что интересно было бы найти где-то пояснение, но я пока не вижу ничего похожего

Comment: @Grundy тогда бы и не писали про дерево, написали бы про документ сразу. В целом это косвенно подтверждается и в других местах, где пишут, что возвращает "первый из элементов с таким id", то есть подразумевается, что он такой может быть и не один.

Comment: @teran, косвенно - это только догадки, и нужно смотреть контекст в котором это все указано.

Comment: @Grundy ну я более чем уверен, что имеется в виду именно ветвь дерева от корня до узла. Думаю любой html валидатор вполне пропустит документ  с одинаковыми id в различных ветках, но возможно выругается если они будут не уникальны в одной ветке.

Answer (score -1):

Если подгружаются разные данные для каждого div, то так:

```
$('#product').each(function (index) {
    $(this).load('/product.html');
});
```

Если в каждый блок подгружается один статичный, то так:

```
$.get('/product.html', function (html) {
    $('#product').html(html);
});
```

Comment: `$('#product').each` не прокатит - так как jquery выберет только один элемент

Comment: [id selector: Selects a **single** element with the given id attribute.](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

Comment: Каждое `id` значение должно использоваться только один раз в документе. Если нескольким элементам был присвоен одинаковый идентификатор, запросы, которые используют этот идентификатор, будут выбирать только первый согласованный элемент в `DOM`. Однако это поведение нельзя полагаться; документ с более чем одним элементом, использующим один и тот же идентификатор, является недопустимым.

Comment: @Grundy, да, точно, помню как-то давно такое прокатывало и больше так не делал )

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev, Ну собственно в первых версиях, он вполне возвращал все элементы соответствующие селектору, Но вот смотрю отдельная ветка для случая `#id` появляется в `1.1.4` что в принципе довольно давно уже.