# Как применить действие ко всем элементам с данным идентификатором, а не только к первому?

Tags: javascript

У меня много элементов с `id="btnDelMessage"`
Проблема в том, что кнопка работает только на самом первом элементе на странице, а на остальных элементах ничего не происходит. Как поправить?

html:

```
<button id="btnDelMessage" value="$id" class="btn btn-sm far fa-trash-alt mr-2"></button>
```

js:

```
$('#btnDelMessage').on('click', function (e) {
        var id = this.value;
        var message = 'Вы действительно хотите удалить сообщение?
        confirmDialog(message, function () {
            //some code
            console.log('Удаляется сообщение: ' + id);
        })
    });

    function confirmDialog(message, onConfirm){
        var fClose = function(){
            modal.modal("hide");
        };
        var modal = $("#modalDelMessage");
        modal.modal("show");
        $("#delMessageText").empty().append(message);
        $("#delMessageOk").one('click', onConfirm);
        $("#delMessageOk").one('click', fClose);
        $("#delMessageCancel").one("click", fClose);
    }
```

Comment: заменить использование id на class. Либо в состав селектора включать родительские элементы, если это разные поддеревья

Comment: еще можно селектор `button[id="btnDelMessage"]`  использовать

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это потому что, `id` на странице должен быть уникальным.

Используйте `class` вместо `id`.

```
<button class="btnDelMessage" value="$id" class="btn btn-sm far fa-trash-alt mr-2"></button>
```

js

```
$('.btnDelMessage').on('click', function (e) {
        var id = this.value;
        var message = 'Вы действительно хотите удалить сообщение?'
        confirmDialog(message, function () {
            //some code
            console.log('Удаляется сообщение: ' + id);
        })
    });

    function confirmDialog(message, onConfirm){
        var fClose = function(){
            modal.modal("hide");
        };
        var modal = $("#modalDelMessage");
        modal.modal("show");
        $("#delMessageText").empty().append(message);
        $("#delMessageOk").one('click', onConfirm);
        $("#delMessageOk").one('click', fClose);
        $("#delMessageCancel").one("click", fClose);
    }
```

Comment: не должен, по крайней мере не на всей странице,

Comment: @teran, я помню был неоконченный спор про не на всей :-)

Comment: @Grundy было дело ;)

Comment: @teran поясните пожалуйста про не на всей. Желательно с примером, если есть возможность. В каком  окружении он может быть не уникальным? Практические примеры?

Comment: дискутировали с @Grundy по этому поводу тут -> https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/820633/223826

Comment: @teran интересная дискуссия. А вот на https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id написано, что во всем документе. Конечно, это не стандарт, но тем не менее, раз так пишут разработчики браузеров, есть вероятность, что они придерживаются такой идеи.

Comment: возможно это рудимент в тексте, [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) внизу ссылки на стандарты есть. и в [HTML4](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#adef-id) он и правда был уникальным на страницу, а вот в [HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/dom.html#the-id-attribute) уже в поддереве.

Comment: @teran Вот там написано *The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's **home subtree***. В то же время - *A node's **home subtree** is the subtree rooted at that node's root element. When a node is in a Document, its home subtree is that Document's tree.* В случае браузера **home subtree** - это весь документ. Так что можно сказать, что должен быть уникальным на всей странице в случае браузерного окружения. Если я, конечно, правильно понял)

Comment: смысл тогда называть все дерево (документ) поддеревом?

Comment: @teran это вопрос не ко мне. Возможно, потому что root элементом в каких-то случаях\окружениях может быть не документ. Кстати, если мы создадим node, но не прикрепим его к документу - у него будет root не document.

Comment: в таком случае это все равно будет отдельное дерево,  а не поддерево.

Comment: @teran а от него будет идти уже поддерево, и в нем id должен быть уникальным. Как только этот новый нод вставится в document, root у него станет document и этот id  должен стать уникальным для всего document.

Comment: я вроде этому не противоречил. в любом случае, переведите дословно что вы процитировали _"home subtree is the subtree rooted at that node's root element"_ -> _"home subtree это поддерево с корнем в родителе данного элемента"_. То есть надо у элемента взять родителя, и все его потомки будут составлять этот home subtree.

Comment: @teran развивайте, пожалуйста, дальше вашу мысль. Что из этого следует?

Comment: что уникальность нужна в home substree, то есть от непосредственного родителя и ниже. И если взять два  независимых home substree, то между ними уникальность не требуется.

Comment: @teran Отлично! В каких случаях бывают независимые home substree?

Comment: вот представьте себе дерево `A -> B -> C#x` и вторая ветка `A -> D -> E#x`, для этих двух элементов `#x` home substree будут `B -> *` и `D -> *`, поскольку общих узлов они не имеют, то они независимы. На практике банально `table -> tr -> td#x`

Comment: По вашему получается, что разные siblings - это разные деревья. Звучит сомнительно!